# Location manager delegate not getting called

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7, cllocationmanager

I am using location service to keep my app alive for longer, its working fine in my iOS6 (Device and Simulator), but in iOS7 its not calling this delegate function of `CLLocationManager`,

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

How to make this work in iOS7?

Comment: it's working fine in iOS6?!?! :)

Answer (score 6):

This method is Deprecated in iOS 6.0

Use this method

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

{
location_updated = [locations lastObject];    
NSLog(@"updated coordinate are %@",location_updated);

}
```

Comment: I used this method. This was not called though

Comment: this is delegate method it will call itself, when you set location manager delegate in your .h file

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

{
location_updated = [locations lastObject];    
 NSLog(@"updated coordinate are %@",location_updated);

 }
```